# Firefox configuration via CLI

Tags: firefox, configuration, command-line-interface

During system setup and later for automatic testing (whether specific configuration settings are still effective) I am interested in configuring Firefox via CLI. I have seen one or the other command line tool but they would always cover only one aspect of Firefox and are usually bound to a specific version.

To be more clear about this, let me list some of the use cases for the CLI:

- create/remove profiles
- install/update/remove plugins
- list installed plugins incl version
- list configuration settings, get/set values (also for plugins)
- clear cache/cookies/...
- manage truststore
- manage bookmarks

Is there no command line interface officially supported?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox command line interface is indeed officially supported, but at this moment in time is under documented. While it's possible to find some [outdated documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions), the in-tree documentation is [only a stub](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/browser/CommandLineParameters.html).

Since you mentioned automated testing, you might also consider the approach [currently being used by Mozilla to run tests on Firefox](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/search?q=--profile&path=test&case=false&regexp=false):

1. Generate a profile to be used for testing.
2. Tweak the preferences in the profile (e.g. using [user.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file)).
3. Start Firefox using the generated profile (either using [-p or --profile](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/78963fe42f8d5f582f84da84a5e78377b6c1fc32/toolkit/xre/nsAppRunner.cpp#1835-1836)).
4. Execute your tests (with Geckodriver?).

Comment: I am sorry, it seems with testing I had something different on my mind. What you describe can quite well be achieved with Selenium where a web application or Firefox itself would be the test subject. I was more aiming at setting up Firefox and testing if those settings were still there. So I updated my question. But the first part of the response is definitely worth a vote.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the upvote. I don't think there's command line options for all the things you need. I'd honestly try to puppet Firefox via Selenium and either use an "about" page (e.g. about:support) or attempt to execute privileged Javascript to get the information you need. Another approach could be to write a WebExtension that does all that you need: during system setup, you could launch Firefox with such an extension to enumerate the capabilities.